# MS SQL Server's equivalent to PostgreSQL's EXPLAIN

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express, sql-server-profiler

Is there a SQL Server equivalent to PostgreSQL's `EXPLAIN` command that I can run on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (ie. without SQL Profiler)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180765(v=sql.105).aspx) before submitting your query to display the execution plan. Do note, though, that it is scheduled to be removed in favour of SHOWPLAN_XML in a future version.